# combine multiple ifs bash

Tags: ubuntu, mac, bash, bash-scripting

how can I simplify the following code if statements? Thank you

```
function git_dirty {
    text=$(git status)
    changed_text="Changes to be committed"
    changes_not_staged="Changes not staged for commit"
    untracked_files="Untracked files"

    dirty=false

    if [[ ${text} = *"$changed_text"* ]];then
        dirty=true
    fi

    if [[ ${text} = *"$changes_not_staged"* ]];then
        dirty=true
    fi

    if [[ ${text} = *"$untracked_files"* ]];then
        dirty=true
    fi

    echo $dirty
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, here is a multi-conditional version of the if, since each statement has the same payload.

```
if [[ ${text} = *"$changed_text"* -o  ${text} = *"$changes_not_staged"* -o ${text} = *"$untracked_files"*]];then
            dirty=true
        fi
```

`-o` between terms in an if specifies an OR relationship between the conditions, and `-a` specifies an AND.

Answer (score 0):

On mac, it complained, so I went to shellcheck.net and it complained about `-o` but didn't say why, just said use `||` so I did:

```
if [[ ${text} = *"$changed_text"* ||  ${text} = *"$changes_not_staged"* || ${text} = *"$untracked_files"* ]]; then
        dirty=true
    fi
```

I was getting

```
$ src
-bash: /Users/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 384: syntax error in conditional expression
-bash: /Users/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 384: syntax error near `-o'
-bash: /Users/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 384: `    if [[ ${text} = *"$changed_text"* -o  ${text} = *"$changes_not_staged"* -o ${text} = *"$untracked_files"* ]]; then'
```